# How to import a PHP project in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, import, xampp

I've to modify a PHP application and I've to load this project in Netbeans to try it in my local system with xampp. Can you help me, please? Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

You go to files/New project choose PHP/PHP Application with existing sources. Choose you sources folder and that's it.